# Is there a way make Visual Studio 11 intellisense ignore boost libraries

Tags: visual-studio, boost, intellisense

Intellisense takes a *very* long time to parse the entirety of boost header files and is one of the things that makes Visual Studio 11 difficult to work with. Particularly in our company workflow of having many branches on the go at once. Is there a way to either:

1. Have a "master" Intellisense database that is parsed once and reused in future solutions/projects?
2. Or prevent Intellisense from delving into boost?